# How to return response entity type according to request type in springboot?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try to develop a global webservice method in my spring boot project and I want to return my response body type according to request body type. Whatever I do, all response return json type.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/virtual/**", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"}, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public class VirtualServiceGateway {

    private IVirtualDocumentService virtualService = UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(IVirtualDocumentService.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response requestGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


        IVirtualDocumentService docService = UtilsForSpring.getSingleBeanOfType(IVirtualDocumentService.class);
        docService.findDocumentByVirtualUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());

        if (docService == null) {

            return Response.status(404).type(request.getContentType()).entity("There is no anything").build();
        }

        return Response.status(200).type(request.getContentType()).entity("ok!").build();

    }
```

Comment: this code cannot compile.    `Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("deneme").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();`
is placed after a unconditional `return` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find something what I want. But I found ResponseEntity, and we can use it like below. In there I can return entity type according to request/response headers.

It works for me, may be useful for somebody

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity requestTEST(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

//        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries"); // xml output format
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all");//json output format
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse res = null;
        StringBuilder resEntity = null;

        try {

            res = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            resEntity = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent()));
            List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(bf);
            for (String line : lines) {
                resEntity.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        for (Header h : res.getAllHeaders()) {
            headers.add(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(resEntity, headers, HttpStatus.valueOf(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
    }
```